# Setup NSPersistentContainer with private queue and main queue NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: swift, core-data

Using an `NSManagedObjectContext` that runs on the main queue and a secondary `NSManagedObjectContext` that runs on a private queue and having them both share an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is a common pattern for syncing with a web service while keeping the UI responsive.

I want to setup my `NSPersistentContainer` to have a `viewContext` and a `backgroundContext` (both `NSManagedObjectContext`).

I see `NSPersistentContainer` already has a `viewContext` property. How can I setup and add to `NSPersistentContainer` a `backgroundContext` property?

This is what I have done so far.

```
class PersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {

    override init(name: String, managedObjectModel model: NSManagedObjectModel) {
        super.init(name: name, managedObjectModel: model)
    }

    private var _backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        get {
            if _backgroundContext == nil {
                _backgroundContext = self.newBackgroundContext()
                _backgroundContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
            }

            return _backgroundContext!
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of nicely adding the `backgroundContext` property to `NSPersistentContainer` other than subclassing?

Comment: If you are looking for a review and possible improvements of *working code* then http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a good place.

Comment: @MartinR the question _"How can I setup and add to `NSPersistentContainer` a `backgroundContext property`?"_ is explicitly off-topic on Code Review, and should be on-topic on Stack Overflow as it is a specific programming question.

Comment: @Phrancis: But this looks like working code to me, ending with *"Is there a better way ...?"* With a different title and introduction it could be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't approached the problem in exactly the same way you posed above, I have been doing some work with the NSPersistentContainer and background contexts and this is what I have found.

I suspect that your code may fail if you implement the above pattern.  The reason: the background context is created with its own private queue, so if you set up the background context on the main queue, it will break the pattern and things get ugly. If you set up the background context on the background queue, then it should be ok, but you must ensure that the background context is never used on another queue/thread.

Up to beta 6 of Xcode (although runtime beta 8 is out there as of today), I have found that using the `performBackgroundTask` to be the most helpful and resilient method of doing things in the background as the code runs in its own closure: whether that works for you will depend on how you are synchronising with the web service.

Another pattern I have used was to start the background task on its own queue and during the startup, get a new background context from the persistent container (which I store in a Singleton pattern) to use during that task. When the task completes, the background context is reclaimed by ARC.

As always, we are still in beta, so things change without notice.